# Proper way to null check in Expression-Tree lambda

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, lambda

First of all, I want to excuse myself for posting a similar question to other existing ones, but I am new to C#, and only starting to grasp LINQ.
I have some business logic across two tables that gets a field of a row. If no such row exists, it should just default to an empty String.
Outside LINQ this would be easy:

```
var res = SomeClass.foo?.bar ?? "";
```

But in LINQ the operators `?.` and `??` are not supported, so I resorted to this:

```
     var projectTask = repository.Set<tblProject>().Where(p => includeInactive ||
                            (p.tblOrderStatus.OrderByDescending(s => s.Date).FirstOrDefault().StatusID != StatusIds.Deducted &&
                            p.tblOrderStatus.OrderByDescending(s => s.Date).FirstOrDefault().StatusID != StatusIds.Deduc_RestDecays &&
                            p.tblOrderStatus.OrderByDescending(s => s.Date).FirstOrDefault().StatusID != StatusIds.Cancelled))
                            .Select(p => new {
                                p.ID,
                                p.CustomerID,
                                p.CenterID,
                                p.FrameworkID,
                                p.DeductionmodeID,
                                p.Code,
                                p.Descriptioln,
                                p.StartDate,
                                p.EndDate,
                                Referencetext = p.tblOrderHistories.Where(m => m.OrderReferencetypeID == 1).OrderByDescending(m => m.Date).FirstOrDefault() != null ?
                                p.tblOrderHistories.Where(m => m.OrderReferencetypeID == 1).OrderByDescending(m => m.Date).FirstOrDefault().Referencetext : ""
                            })
                            .ToListAsync();
```

Where I do the Query twice, which isn't performance killing in this case, but still not very elegant.

I understand you can construct LINQ expressions through `Expression`, but I can't quite find an example of my case.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But in LINQ the operators `?.` and `??` are not supported

I guess by LINQ here you mean LINQ against `IQueryable` (inside expression trees) because in LINQ against `IEnumerable` (with delegates) both are supported.

While you are right that `?.` operator is not supported in the expression trees (yet), the `??` is perfectly supported.

So if the question is for this expression:

```
Referencetext = 
    p.tblOrderHistories.Where(m => m.OrderReferencetypeID == 1)
        .OrderByDescending(m => m.Date).FirstOrDefault() != null ?
    p.tblOrderHistories.Where(m => m.OrderReferencetypeID == 1)
        .OrderByDescending(m => m.Date).FirstOrDefault().Referencetext : ""
```

it can easily be handled with combination of `Select`, `FirstOrDefault` and `??` operator:

```
Referencetext = p.tblOrderHistories
    .Where(m => m.OrderReferencetypeID == 1)
    .OrderByDescending(m => m.Date)
    .Select(m => m.Referencetext)
    .FirstOrDefault() ?? ""
```

Comment: Thanks! But will `.FirstOrDefault()` ever return null?

Comment: For nullable types, absolutely (`null` is what the `Default` word inside `XyzOrDefault` means)